# Play Framework Modeling

Tags: playframework, sbt, playframework-2.0, ebean

I'm new to Play framework using Java and need some help on how the Modeling works using Ebean to connect to mysql database, what I want to do now is to create models and I have succeeded on connecting to database and connecting to it with the conventional steps on Play Framework Documentation, but the steps seems to be outdated and showing errors.

Would anyone please reference or recommend me a tutorial to handle this?

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions.

Comment: I haven't found any comprehensive play tutorials.  To learn more about Ebean models, take a look at Play's Ebean documentation - https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.6.x/JavaEbean